# Is there any other better approach

Tags: c++, qt, shared-memory

QT Paintevent is not painting the required image, instead paints black screen. this paintevent is called for each time interval of 2 seconds using SLOT(update).

I have tried with triggering PaintImage method that is Implemented to draw QImage supplied, but didnt work either.

```
void Client::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{

        //qWarning() << image.isNull() << image.width()<< image.height();
        QPainter painter(&image);
        painter.end();
        QPixmap pixMap;//(image);
        //painter.drawImage(1280, 639, image);
        bool b = pixMap.convertFromImage(image);
        QLabel w;
        w.setPixmap(pixMap);
        w.show();
}
```

Expected actual Image to be displayed but ending up blank screen.

Comment: Your `QLabel` is locally scoped within `paintEvent`.  It will be destroyed as soon as `paintEvent` completes.

Answer (score 1):

Add QLabel as a member of class (Client) ... lets give it name m_my_label.
Then in paintEvent say just m_my_label.setPixmap(pixMap) and m_my_label.show().

Problem is that QLabel is local variable and will cease to exist when you go out of paintEvent function.

Comment: thank you for your time in answering my query. When I make QLabel part of class and moment it finds the image details it crashes Immediately without displaying the Image. Do I need to take care of anything more beyond this steps. your inputs are much appreciated. Thanks & Regards,Rudresh

Comment: This line if I comment app will not crash but ending up with no Image displayed.            vlcStream.setPixmap(pixMap);

Comment: This Issue is solved - there is a issue with Image Format lead to crash. Thank you Mr. Golobich for your inputs and it helped alot.